# How to connect semanti-ui to nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, semantic-ui, nuxt.js

I run `npm i semantic-ui --save` then I run `gulp build` finally i connect semantic.min.css in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  css: [
  '~/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'
  ],
```

But I want connect semantic.min.js too for popus and modals, or i should write logic by vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the head section of `nuxt.config.js` file, you can add this:

```js
export default {
...
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: '~/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js'}
    ]
  }
...
```

But I think you're going the wrong way to integrate nuxt.js and semantic-ui...
You should follow `semantic-ui-vue` package and [integration with nuxt](https://github.com/Semantic-UI-Vue/Semantic-UI-Vue#nuxtjs-module) instead.

Comment: Yes, but this package very old.